# C++ VS2010 Communication between two different projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm pretty new to programming and I've written a parser in C++ VS2010, the .exe of which is to be called by another application when importing files of a particular extension. The parsed files are given another extension and subsequently opened.

The problem is: for some files, the parsing takes a few seconds, by which time the application has already looked for the file with the new extension and either opened an older version of it, or given an error message because the file syntax doesn't fit (the file with the new extension not having been completely written).

Is there any way of of making the application wait until the parsing has finished? i tried to use an fstream to open a file in the parser and close when parsing is finished with a `while` loop in the application asking if the fstream was still open but it didn't work. Other than implementing some 
`for`
loop with a few seconds delay (not very pretty), I can't quite think what to do. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a library project, not an EXE project.  If you want help with your code then you have to show it.

Comment: Don't try to synchronize via the file system, wait for the child process to finish.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters but I don't know how to wait for the child process to finish, that's the issue. So i generated a temp file using the parser main function which gets subsequently removed once parsing is finished, and wanted to use a `while` loop in the application to ascertain if the file still exists. But the problem with that is: for some reason, the temp file doesn't get generated when calling the parser .exe, it only gets generated in debugging mode. Have you maybe any ideas as to why that happens? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, sorry - I see no source code, and my crystal ball is foggy.